# Unable to destroy persistent store created with Core Data and SQLite

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an iOS app where I want to start with a fresh Core Data database on every launch. The store type is SQLite.

However, when I call persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(), I get an error 100% of the time.

Here is the code:

```
func destroyPersistentStore() {
    guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.modelName, withExtension: "momd") else {
        print("Missing data model - could not destroy")
        return
    }

    do {
        try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: modelURL, ofType: storeType, options: nil)
    } catch  {
        print("Unable to destroy persistent store: \(error) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
}
```

The error is:

> Unable to destroy persistent store: Error Domain=NSSQLiteErrorDomain
>   Code=14 "(null)" UserInfo={NSFilePath=.../AppName.app/ModelName.momd,
>   reason=Failed to truncate database} - The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSSQLiteErrorDomain error 14.)

Even after this error, the app is able to save and access data in the store. The problem is that the initial data is being loaded on each launch, creating duplicates.

Here is the situation at the point where the call to destroyPersistentStore takes place:

1. The SQLite data file definitely exists and contains data
2. Happens on simulator or real device
3. The modelUrl is correct and points to the momd
4. Store type is SQLite
5. SQLite data file is saved in Documents directory
6. persistentStoreCoordinator.url(for: persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first!) is pointing to the file in the Documents directory.

I've searched online for answers and can't find anyone reporting this error, but I have the error in both this project and a simplified demo project. I cannot make destroyPersistentStore work at all.

Lastly, when I pause execution and po the persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel, the first line is:

> po persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel
>   () isEditable 0, entities...

Could the isEditable issue be the problem? How would I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're conflating two objects in the Core Data stack:

- The **model** is inside your app bundle, has the extension `.momd`, and contains information about your Core Data object definitions: what entities you have, what properties they have, their relationships, and so on.
- The **persistent store** is a data file in your app's container (not in the bundle). You define its URL when you create or load persistent stores. It contains data for actual instances of model objects, rather than abstract definitions.

Rather than getting the URL of your model, I think you want to get the URL of a persistent store. You can do that by looking at the persistent store coordinator's `persistentStores` array, picking one, and getting its URL:

```
func destroyPersistentStore() {
    guard let firstStoreURL = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first?.url else {
        print("Missing first store URL - could not destroy")
        return
    }

    do {
        try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: firstStoreURL, ofType: storeType, options: nil)
    } catch  {
        print("Unable to destroy persistent store: \(error) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
}
```

This would destroy the first store; if you have multiple, you could instead loop over the persistent stores destroying them all, depending on your app's requirements.

Comment: Thank you. Been pulling what's left of my hair out!

Answer (score 4):

**iOS 15 version**

```
// function to delete persistent store

func deletePersistentStore() {
    let coordinator = self.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
    guard let store = coordinator.persistentStores.first else {
        return
    }
    let storeURL = coordinator.url(for: store)
    do {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let storeType: NSPersistentStore.StoreType = inMemoryStore ? .inMemory : .sqlite
            try coordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: storeURL, type: storeType)
        } else {
            let storeType: String = inMemoryStore ? NSInMemoryStoreType : NSSQLiteStoreType
            try coordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: storeURL, ofType: storeType)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this great solution:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension NSManagedObjectContext
{
    func deleteAllData()
    {
        guard let persistentStore = persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores.last else {
            return
        }

        guard let url = persistentStoreCoordinator?.url(for: persistentStore) else {
            return
        }

        performAndWait { () -> Void in
            self.reset()
            do
            {
                try self.persistentStoreCoordinator?.remove(persistentStore)
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
                try self.persistentStoreCoordinator?.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
            }
            catch { /*dealing with errors up to the usage*/ }
        }
    }
}
```