# destroyPersistentStore failed to delete the persistent store - CoreData: error: Failed to delete support directory for store

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to delete a persistent store from my Swift code. Every time I try, the store does not get deleted and I get an error that is not caught in the catch block that states the following:

CoreData: error: Failed to delete support directory for store: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8292CDAE-8AE4-4353-8F4C-0EB12CF119CC/Library/Application Support/Chapter.sqlite

When I check, all of the files are there, Chapter.sqlite, Chapter.sqlite-shm and Chapter.sqlite-wal. Nothing is deleted. I thought, based on some other posts, that perhaps a lock was held on the store. However, I have this problem even when I relaunch the application and the first thing I try is to delete the store with the following code:

```
container = NSPersistentContainer( name: "Chapter" )
do {
            let url = getApplicationSupportDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Chapter.sqlite")
            
            try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: url, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
        }
        catch {
            print( error )
        }
```

I also tried loading the store first, to get the url from a loaded store using:

```
container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            caughtError = error as NSError?
        }

do {
            let store = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last!
            
            //try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(store)
        
            try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: store.url!, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
        }
        catch {
            print( error )
        }
```

I got the same error, both with the line container.persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(store) commented and uncommented.

The store does not get deleted at all. Not even the .sqlite file. Has anyone encountered a problem like this? How did you solve it? Are there some other ways to delete the persistent store? I suppose I could delete the files 'manually', using FileManager but I worry that might come with issues of its own down the line. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is getApplicationSupportDirectory in reply to @TomHarrington:

```
func getApplicationSupportDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

To @ElTomato, unfortunately no, [Unable to destroy persistent store created with Core Data and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995296/unable-to-destroy-persistent-store-created-with-core-data-and-sqlite) does not solve it for me. I am not passing a file with extension .mmod to destroyPeristentStore, but the .sqlite file. Also, I used in one of the attempts the url taken directly from the store object obtained from persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Would you mind rewording your heading into a more refined question? This will allow experienced users to more easily help you with your question.

Comment: @tdelozie thanks for the suggestion. I changed the title and included the error in it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to destroy persistent store created with Core Data and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995296/unable-to-destroy-persistent-store-created-with-core-data-and-sqlite)

Comment: What happens in `getApplicationSupportDirectory`? All I can think of is that somehow you're caching the app support path, which could mean the UUID is bad. That seems unlikely but it's all I've got.

Comment: @TomHarrington I updated the post with the content of getApplicationSupportDirectory. It does not seem to be the case of caching, as I tried to get the url from the persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores. Thanks for the suggestion. Let me know if anything else catches your eye. Also could it be some kind of file permission issue? I can write, and read, but not delete perhaps? I will look into that now.

Comment: @ElTomato does not seem like it. The person is trying to delete .mmod file. I also tried getting the url from the persistentStores. It just occurred to me, could it be some kind of file permissions? read/write, I guess not read, write as I can do that, but delete permission perhaps?