# CoreData: Is there a way to cleanly delete the backuped DB, after database backup via migratePersistentStore?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Currently, our app provides a backup functionality to user, where she can perform snapshot backup of app database.

We are using `migratePersistentStore` to achieve such functionality.

After running `migratePersistentStore`, we will execute other I/O operations. Some of the I/O operations might fail. In such case, we need to completely delete the backup-ed database.

**However, we notice it is very difficult to delete the backup-ed database!**

We notice at certain point, CoreData will re-create the SQLite file, even though we have perform `destroyPersistentStore` and `FileManager.default.removeItem`.

Here's our code snippet.

```
public static func cloneXXXDatabase(dstUrl: URL, directory: Directory, cloneTrash: Bool) -> Bool {
    // Current already opened app database.
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
    guard let srcUrl = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url else { return false }
    
    // New destination to backup current app database.
    let coreDataNamedStack = CoreDataNamedStack(srcUrl)
    // Have a new NSPersistentStoreCoordinator solely for migration purpose.
    let psc = coreDataNamedStack.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
    
    // Open the SQLite. Is it fine for 2 different NSPersistentStoreCoordinator to access 1 same SQLite?
    guard let srcStore = psc.persistentStore(for: srcUrl) else { return false }

    do {
        // Reference: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/write-ahead-logging-wal/
        // This is to ensure only 1 SQLite file is produced, without WAL & SHM.
        let options = [NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"]]
        try psc.migratePersistentStore(srcStore, to: dstUrl, options: options, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
    } catch {
        error_log(error)
        return false
    }
    
    // ...
    // ... (some other I/O operations)
    // ...
    
    var somethingWentWrong = true
    
    if somethingWentWrong {
        do {
            try psc.destroyPersistentStore(at: dstUrl, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
            
            if dstUrl.exists {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstUrl)
            }
            
            print(">>>> DELETE \(dstUrl)")
            
            //
            // WARNING: Such SQLite removal code is not working, and I am not sure why?!
            // It seems that after returning from this function, CoreData will still re-create the backup destination
            // DB, by logging
            //
            // CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at ".../xxx.sqlite".
            //
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
        }
    }
    
    return true
}
```

---

Do you have idea, how can we cleanly delete the SQLite file, which is generated via `migratePersistentStore`? `destroyPersistentStore` and `FileManager.default.removeItem` do not seem to work.

Thank you.

---

Here's the code of `CoreDataStack` (Core data stack for main app), and `CoreDataNamedStack` (Core data stack which points to the backup destination)

### CoreDataStack (Core data stack for main app)

```
class CoreDataStack {
    static let INSTANCE = CoreDataStack()
    
    private init() {
    }
    
    private(set) lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "xxx", managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel.wenote)
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // This is a serious fatal error. We will just simply terminate the app, rather than using error_log.
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        // So that when backgroundContext write to persistent store, container.viewContext will retrieve update from
        // persistent store.
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        return container
    }()
}
```

### CoreDataNamedStack (Core data stack which points to the backup destination)

```
class CoreDataNamedStack: CoreDataStackable {
    let url: URL
    
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    private(set) lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "xxx", managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel.wenote)
        
        let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // This is a serious fatal error. We will just simply terminate the app, rather than using error_log.
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        // So that when backgroundContext write to persistent store, container.viewContext will retrieve update from
        // persistent store.
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        return container
    }()
}
```

### Finding

Instead of executing the following deletion code immediately

```
var somethingWentWrong = true

if somethingWentWrong {
    do {
        try psc.destroyPersistentStore(at: dstUrl, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
        
        if dstUrl.exists {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstUrl)
        }
        
        print(">>>> DELETE \(dstUrl)")
    } catch {
        error_log(error)
    }
}
```

If we delay a few seconds before executing deletion code.

```
    var somethingWentWrong = true
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            
        if somethingWentWrong {
            do {
                try psc.destroyPersistentStore(at: dstUrl, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
                
                if dstUrl.exists {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstUrl)
                }
                
                print(">>>> DELETE \(dstUrl)")
            } catch {
                error_log(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then such removal will success.

My guess is, CoreData has a background thread commit changes to disk. If the deletion happens before the disk changes committed, database file re-creation will happen again.

May I know what is a proper way to solve this, without having an arbitrary/ random delayed code block?

Comment: Does this answer help? (Instead of using the old dstUrl for delete maybe try refetching new URL using the CoreData api ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995296/unable-to-destroy-persistent-store-created-with-core-data-and-sqlite

Comment: No yet. I have updated my finding.

Answer (score 2):

Observations that I have noted from your code snippets:

1. You used the deprecated method on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468927-migratepersistentstore)
2. To migrate from srcStore URL to dstStore it will take time for migration using `migratePersistentStore()` so, you have to check if the whole migration is completed before deleting the backup-ed database.

To do it you can check the status of migration and `destroyPersistentStore` ple:

```
let migrationResult = try psc.migratePersistentStore(srcStore, to: dstUrl, options: options, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)

if migrationResult {
    do {
        try psc.destroyPersistentStore(at: dstUrl, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
        
        if dstUrl.exists {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstUrl)
        }
        
        print(">>>> DELETE \(dstUrl)")
        
        //
        // WARNING: Such SQLite removal code is not working, and I am not sure why?!
        // It seems that after returning from this function, CoreData will still re-create the backup destination
        // DB, by logging
        //
        // CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at ".../xxx.sqlite".
        //
    } catch {
        error_log(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this on my end, but the `destroyPersistentStore` method or the `removeItem` method might want to be called from the main thread. That could be why it works after a delay, as the `asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2)` method runs the code after a delay in the main thread.

You could try this:

```
var somethingWentWrong = true

DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
    if somethingWentWrong {
        do {
            try psc.destroyPersistentStore(at: dstUrl, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
            
            if dstUrl.exists {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstUrl)
            }
            
            print(">>>> DELETE \(dstUrl)")
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
        }
    }
}
```